# Android Combined bar and line graph MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [`MpAndroidChart`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for graphs. I want to combine bar graph and line graph together. I am referring to the `CombinedBarChart Activity` of the MpAndroidChart Example. I am not able to remove stack bar. How to remove it ?

Below is the bar chart data :

```
ArrayList<BarEntry> entries1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++) {
        entries1.add(new BarEntry(0, getRandom(25, 25)));

        // stacked
        entries2.add(new BarEntry(0, new float[]{getRandom(13, 12), getRandom(13, 12)}));
    }

    BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(entries1, "Bar 1");
    set1.setColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
    set1.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
    set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

    BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(entries2, "");
    set2.setStackLabels(new String[]{"Stack 1", "Stack 2"});
    set2.setColors(new int[]{Color.rgb(61, 165, 255), Color.rgb(23, 197, 255)});
    set2.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(61, 165, 255));
    set2.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

    float groupSpace = 0.06f;
    float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
    float barWidth = 0.45f; // x2 dataset
    // (0.45 + 0.02) * 2 + 0.06 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"

    BarData d = new BarData(set1);
    d.setBarWidth(barWidth);

    // make this BarData object grouped
    d.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace); // start at x = 0
```

If I remove stack I get only one bar.

Comment: If you want bar and line combined together , why are you using only `BarEntry` as the data set ? shouldn't  you also use `LineData` to get the Line representation ?

Comment: I am using that also. I am getting that properly. But I am not getting bar graph.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where you create the data, you are always setting the first element of the entries and therefore will only produce the one column for the "Bar 1" data. You need to increment the x index when adding your data.

```
  for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++) {
        entries1.add(new BarEntry(index, getRandom(25, 25)));
    }
```

Also note I am not sure what your getRandom is actually doing, but it looks like it is producing a random value between 25 & 25. I am not sure if this is the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this.

```
public class BarChartActivity extends DemoBase implements OnSeekBarChangeListener,
    OnChartValueSelectedListener {

protected CombinedChart mChart;
private SeekBar mSeekBarX, mSeekBarY;
private TextView tvX, tvY;
private int[] COLOR = {
        ColorTemplate.rgb("#F8F8F8"), ColorTemplate.rgb("#FFFFFF")
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_barchart);

    tvX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvXMax);
    tvY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvYMax);

    mSeekBarX = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    mSeekBarY = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);

    mChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);

    mChart.setDescription("");

    // if more than 60 entries are displayed in the chart, no values will be
    // drawn
    mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);

    // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);

    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    // mChart.setDrawYLabels(false);

    IAxisValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new DayAxisValueFormatter(mChart);

    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
    xAxis.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // only intervals of 1 day
    xAxis.setLabelCount(7);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);

    IAxisValueFormatter custom = new MyAxisValueFormatter();

    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
    leftAxis.setValueFormatter(custom);
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

    YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    rightAxis.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    rightAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
    rightAxis.setValueFormatter(custom);
    rightAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
    rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

    Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
    l.setPosition(LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_LEFT);
    l.setForm(LegendForm.SQUARE);
    l.setFormSize(9f);
    l.setTextSize(11f);
    l.setXEntrySpace(4f);
    // l.setExtra(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS, new String[] { "abc",
    // "def", "ghj", "ikl", "mno" });
    // l.setCustom(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS, new String[] { "abc",
    // "def", "ghj", "ikl", "mno" });

    XYMarkerView mv = new XYMarkerView(this, xAxisFormatter);
    mv.setChartView(mChart); // For bounds control
    mChart.setMarker(mv); // Set the marker to the chart

    setData(20, 50);

    // setting data
    mSeekBarY.setProgress(50);
    mSeekBarX.setProgress(12);

    mSeekBarY.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    mSeekBarX.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    // mChart.setDrawLegend(false);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bar, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.actionToggleValues: {
            for (IDataSet set : mChart.getData().getDataSets())
                set.setDrawValues(!set.isDrawValuesEnabled());

            mChart.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.actionToggleHighlight: {
            if (mChart.getData() != null) {
                mChart.getData().setHighlightEnabled(!mChart.getData().isHighlightEnabled());
                mChart.invalidate();
            }
            break;
        }
        case R.id.actionTogglePinch: {
            if (mChart.isPinchZoomEnabled())
                mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
            else
                mChart.setPinchZoom(true);

            mChart.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.actionToggleAutoScaleMinMax: {
            mChart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(!mChart.isAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled());
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.actionToggleBarBorders: {
            /*for (IBarDataSet set : mChart.getData().getDataSets())
                ((BarDataSet) set).setBarBorderWidth(set.getBarBorderWidth() == 1.f ? 0.f : 1.f);*/

            mChart.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.animateX: {
            mChart.animateX(3000);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.animateY: {
            mChart.animateY(3000);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.animateXY: {

            mChart.animateXY(3000, 3000);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.actionSave: {
            if (mChart.saveToGallery("title" + System.currentTimeMillis(), 50)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saving SUCCESSFUL!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saving FAILED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

    tvX.setText("" + (mSeekBarX.getProgress() + 2));
    tvY.setText("" + (mSeekBarY.getProgress()));

    setData(mSeekBarX.getProgress() + 1, mSeekBarY.getProgress());
    mChart.invalidate();
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

private void setData(int count, float range) {

    float start = 0f;

    mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(start);
    mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(start + count + 2);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    int size = (int)(start + count + 1);

    int[] COLOR_LINE = new int[size];
    for (int i = (int) start; i < 10; i++) {
        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(i + 1f, 300));
    }

    for (int i = (int) start; i < 5; i++) {
        float mult = (range + 1);
        float val = getRandom(90, 50); //float val = (float) (Math.random() * mult);




        entries.add(new Entry(i + 1f, val));
        COLOR_LINE[i] = (val < 70 ? Color.RED : Color.rgb(115, 180, 236));

    }


    LineData d = new LineData();

    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Line DataSet");
    set.setColors(COLOR_LINE);
    set.setLineWidth(1f);
    set.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setCircleRadius(5f);
    set.setFillColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.LINEAR);
    set.setDrawValues(true);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(115, 180, 236));

    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    d.addDataSet(set);


    BarDataSet set1;

    if (mChart.getData() != null &&
            mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
        set1 = (BarDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(yVals1);
        mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "The year 2017");
        set1.setColors(COLOR);

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        data.setValueTextSize(10f);
        data.setValueTypeface(mTfLight);
        data.setBarWidth(0.9f);
        data.setBarWidth(1f);

        //mChart.setData(data);

        CombinedData combinedData = new CombinedData();

        combinedData.setData(data);
        combinedData.setData(d);
        combinedData.setValueTypeface(mTfLight);


        mChart.setData(combinedData);
        mChart.setScaleMinima((float) (data.getXMax() + 0.25f)/10f, 1f);
        for (IDataSet set11 : mChart.getData().getDataSets()) {
            if (set11 instanceof BarDataSet)
                set11.setDrawValues(!set11.isDrawValuesEnabled());
        }

        mChart.invalidate();
    }
}

protected RectF mOnValueSelectedRectF = new RectF();

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {

    if (e == null)
        return;

    RectF bounds = mOnValueSelectedRectF;
    //mChart.getBarBounds((BarEntry) e, bounds);
    MPPointF position = mChart.getPosition(e, AxisDependency.LEFT);

    Log.i("bounds", bounds.toString());
    Log.i("position", position.toString());

    Log.i("x-index",
            "low: " + mChart.getLowestVisibleX() + ", high: "
                    + mChart.getHighestVisibleX());

    MPPointF.recycleInstance(position);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected() {
}
```

}